# Cannot change JButton ActionCommand inside ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton, actionlistener

I cannot seem to change JButton ActionCommand inside an ActionListener. I am trying to use the same two buttons multiple time by changing the ActionCommand, but that doesn't seem to work.
Here's my code, hopefully you can help:

```
void ChangeAction() {
    storyButn1.setActionCommand("but3");
    storyButn2.setActionCommand("but4");
}

public Main() {

    story.setText("<html>You wake up with a sore head in a dark forest. You can't remember anything, except from the word H.E.L.P. You see a light in the distance, What to do? </html>");

    storyButn1.addActionListener(this);
    storyButn1.setActionCommand("but1");

    storyButn2.addActionListener(this);
    storyButn2.setActionCommand("but2");

    Box Layout = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    Layout.add(story);
    Layout.setSize(story.getWidth() + 10, story.getHeight());

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(Layout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(storyButn1);
    frame.add(storyButn2);
    frame.setTitle("Text Adventure");

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but1")) {
        random = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()) * 10);
        if (random == 10) {
            story.setText("<html>You run towards the light source. It's dark and you don't see that root in the ground. You break your ankle!</html>");
            storyButn1
                    .setText("<html>Lay against a tree and hope for the best?</html>");
            storyButn2.setText("<html>Call out for help?</html>");
        } else {
            story.setText("<html>You walk carefully towards the light source, When you reach it, you find that it is a torch.</html>");
            storyButn1.setText("Pick it up?");
            storyButn2.setText("Switch it off?");
        }
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but2")) {
        random = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()) * 20);
        if (random == 20) {
            story.setText("<html>You are near the top of the tree when your foot slips. You go plummeting back into the darkness, never to be seen again.");
            storyButn1.setText("Retry?");
            storyButn2.setText("Retry?");
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but1") || e.getActionCommand().equals("but2")) {
                this.dispose();
                frame.setVisible(false);
                new Main();             
            }
        } else {
            story.setText("<html>You successfully climb to the top of the tree where you find a safe spot to sit. You stay there for a while, *BANG*, You hear something in the distance!</html>");
            ChangeAction();
            storyButn1.setText("Climb down and investigate?");
            storyButn2.setText("Follow the light source?");

                if(e.getActionCommand().equals("but3")){
                    story.setText("<html>You slowly climb down the tree. When you reach the bottom, you try to follow where you think the sound had come from. As your walking you look down. There is a loaded revolver with one bullet missing and a trail of blood.</html>");
                } else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("but4")){
                    story.setText("<html>You walk carefully towards the light source, When you reach it, you find that it is a torch.</html>");
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - *"As your walking you look down."*  should be *"As you're walking you look down."*

Comment: it's still in dev stages, and that wasn't the question

Comment: *"it's still in dev stages,"*  Does that mean "No, I don't want better help sooner?"  *"and that wasn't the question"*  Hence my 'not an answer' - that's what ***comments*** are for.

Comment: You are nowhere setting the `actioncommand` of `JButton` within `actionlistener` method..

Comment: Where in the code posted do you change the action command?

Comment: alright, well thanks for adding th "'" and "e" onto my code.

Comment: Yes, please show us the ChangeAction() method

Comment: I *could* write a <50 line app. that can change the text of a button, but then you'd likely say WTE *"That doesn't work for me because of blah, blah.."*  - I don't intend wasting my time on that approach.  Post an SSCCE or ..good luck with it.

Comment: there we go @JosephBueno

Comment: @Mac I've added that into the code^

Comment: No, Your new code still not reflecting that you are changing the `actionCommand` within `actionListener`

Comment: @Mac look at void ChangeAction, i am running that inside of the actionlistener, therefore I am running what is inside ChangeAction inside an actionlistener

Comment: Can you show the code for `ChangeAction`?

Comment: @mac I AM, void ChangeAction() {
    storyButn1.setActionCommand("but3");
    storyButn2.setActionCommand("but4");
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one place where you do something if the action command is `"but3"` or `"but4"`, and this place is inside the following if block:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but2")) {
```

Obviously, it's impossible for the action command to be both `"but2"` and `"but3"` or `"but4"`. It's one or the other.

So the conditions of the following `if` blocks will always evaluate to `false`:

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("but3")){
    story.setText("<html>You slowly climb down the tree. When you reach the bottom, you try to follow where you think the sound had come from. As your walking you look down. There is a loaded revolver with one bullet missing and a trail of blood.</html>");
} else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("but4")){
    story.setText("<html>You walk carefully towards the light source, When you reach it, you find that it is a torch.</html>");
}
```

EDIT:

to recap, the `actionPerformed()` method looks like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but1")) {
        // do something
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but2")) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It doesn't handle the case where the action command is `"but3"` or `"but4"`.

Comment: So how can I set my JButton to have a different ActionCommand?

Comment: You're doing it already. The problem is not changing the action command. It's doing something in actionPerformed when the event has this new action command. At the moment, your code only handles two action commands : but1 and but2. For all the other action commands, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for explaining I now understand my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Tried it out and it's now fixed!

Answer (score 0):

you can't reach this part of code

```
else {
        story.setText("<html>You successfully climb to the top of the tree where you find a safe spot to sit. You stay there for a while, *BANG*, You hear something in the distance!</html>");
        ChangeAction();
        storyButn1.setText("Climb down and investigate?");
        storyButn2.setText("Follow the light source?");
    }
```

and here where you call ChangeAction().
test using `system.out.println("inside else");` you will see that this line will never be printed.

you need to use ChangeAction() somewhere inside the 1st two if statments